# Route fallback for POST methods in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes

Is there a way to check route fallback for post methods? This code works for any get url in my routes file i.e. I get this response("Page Not Found.") if I type and wrong GET url.

Is there a way to check the same for POST urls?

```
Route::fallback(function(){
    return response()->json([
        'status'    => false,
        'message'   => 'Page Not Found.',
    ], 404);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
use Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

In app/Exceptions/Handler.php replace render function

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if (Request::isMethod('post') && $exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Page Not Found',
                'status' => false
                ], 500
            );
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Or if you want both NotFound And MethodNotAllowed then

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ((Request::isMethod('post') && $exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) || (Request::isMethod('post') && $exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Page Not Found',
                'status' => false
                ], 500
            );
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Akash, i changed the code accordingly and i'm getting this error

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: change instance of  to MethodNotAllowedHttpException. pls check updated answer

Comment: It works. Thanks. Just had to add use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;

Answer (score 15):

Define custom fallback route at end of your routes/api.php

```
Route::any('{any}', function(){
    return response()->json([
        'status'    => false,
        'message'   => 'Page Not Found.',
    ], 404);
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 3):

Put this script end of your routes file.

```
Route::any('{url?}/{sub_url?}', function(){
    return response()->json([
        'status'    => false,
        'message'   => 'Page Not Found.',
    ], 404);
})
```

It will automatically detect if someone try to hit any other routes like below.

```
laravel_project_path/public/any_string
laravel_project_path/public/any_string/any_string
```

Comment: It's not working. And the given code is now not working on GET url as well. And do I need to pass something in {url} ?

Comment: This can be done only up to 2 depth. Use regex with where().

Answer (score 0):

Try:
**In Route API**

```
Route::fallback(function () { abort(500);  });
```

**In resources folder**

Follow:

1. Go to resources
2. Go to views
3. Create **errors** folder
4. Create blade **500.blade.php**

Answer (score 0):

Create an **any** request with any URL.

```
//in web.php

Route::any('{any}', function(){
    return 'Hello, I will accept any type of request!';
})->where('any', '.*');
```

You may receive '419 PAGE EXPIRED' error for POST requests. It is because of CsrfToken. You can globally disable the CSRF token check, which is **not a recommended method** as it causes security risks.

```
//in \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

protected $except = [
        '*' //Allow for all, or write custom exceptions. 
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

**REASON**   :  composer has not seen this URL yet.

**SOLUTION** :

1. check if this URL is defined to your composer through `php artisan route:list` command.
2. if the URL is not defined """"use the `php artisan route:clear` command to refresh routes.
3. then you can use `php artisan route:list` command again, to check that URL has been defined.

Answer (score -1):

You can use given method to check POST URL and return 404 error page. Please keep the code in web.php at the last line.

```
Route::fallback(function(){
    return \Response::view('errors.404');
});
```